# include() method for nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am struggling with checking an array for an array within. It doesn't seem that the `include()` method is designed for it because it always returns `false` in this case. Below is example of an identical scenario with `indexOf`. Maybe all I need is syntax help, any ideas are most welcome.

```
arr = [1,[9,9],3,4,5];

if (arr.indexOf(el) !== -1) {
   console.log(`the array contains ${el}`);
} else {
   console.log(`doesn't contain ${el}`);
}
```

Of course the above returns `true` for 1, 3, 4, 5 and `false` for 2. And now the problem. I am trying to feed this method with an array like `[9,9]` to see if there's one already.

```
let el = [9,9];
// console: "doesn't contain 9,9"
```

On the other hand the below is okay which makes me think it's just a syntax issue(?)

```
let el = arr[1];
// console: "the array contains 9,9"
```

I found a way around it by writing a checker function with `for` loop but this quickly becomes bulky as you add requirements. I would love to know a smarter way.

Thank you.

Comment: I have updated my answer to add a succinct implementation not using JSON.stringify(), in order to make it more complete.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to loop through the array and check if each element is an array, then you check each index.  Something like this:

```js
let arr = [1,[9,9],3,4,5];
let el = [9,9];
let contains = true;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
    var equals = true
    if(arr[i].length !== el.length)
        equals = false;
    for(var j = arr[i].length; j--;) {
        if(arr[i][j] !== el[j])
           equals = false;
    }  
    if (equals) {    
      contains = true;
      break;
    }
  } else {
    if (arr.indexOf(el) !== -1){
        contains = true;        
        break;
      }
    else{contains = false;}
  }
}

if (contains) {
  console.log(`the array contains ${el}`);
} else {
  console.log(`doesn't contain ${el}`)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem you have is that **arrays are reference types**. Because of this, comparing two arrays will return true only if the two arrays refer to the same underlying array, and will return false for different arrays, even if they hold the same values.

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2];
const arr2 = [1, 2];
const arr3 = arr1;

console.log(arr1 === arr3);
console.log(arr1 !== arr2);
```

To fix your problem, your `include` function needs to **compare by value (deep comparison)**, you can do this simply using `JSON.stringify()`.

> This method is fast but limited, it works when you have simple JSON-style objects without methods and DOM nodes inside

See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript) about object comparison in JavaScript.

Here is a working example:

```js
function include(arr, value) {
  const stringifiedValue = JSON.stringify(value);
  for (const val of arr) {
    if (JSON.stringify(val) === stringifiedValue) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(include([1, 2, 3, 4], 3));
console.log(include([1, 2, 3, [1, 2]], [1, 2]));
console.log(include([1, 2, 3, [1, 2]], [1, 2, 3]));
```

Here is **another way** to do this deep comparison without `JSON.stringify()`, it works for inner arrays, and scalar values:

```js
function include(arr, value) {
  const valArity = Array.isArray(value) ? value.length : 1;
  for (let item of arr) {
    if (valArity > 1 && Array.isArray(item) && item.length === valArity) {
      if (item.every((val, i) => val === value[i])) {
        return true;
      }
    } else if (item === value) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(include([1, 2, 3, 4], 3));
console.log(include([1, 2, 3, [1, 2]], [1, 2]));
console.log(include([1, 2, 3, [1, 2]], [1, 2, 3]));
console.log(include([1, 2, 'abc', 4], 'abc'));
```

And here is a modified version that works for simple **objects with scalar properties, arrays and scalars**:

```js
function include(arr, value) {
  const valArity = Array.isArray(value) ? value.length : 1;
  const isObject = value instanceof Object;
  for (let item of arr) {
    if (valArity > 1 && Array.isArray(item) && item.length === valArity) {
      if (item.every((val, i) => val === value[i])) {
        return true;
      }
    } else if (isObject && item instanceof Object && item) {
      const numEntries = Object.keys(value).length;
      const entries = Object.entries(item);
      if (numEntries === entries.length) {
        if (entries.every(([k, v]) => value[k] === v)) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    } else if (item === value) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(include([1, 2, 3, 4], 3));
console.log(include([1, 2, 3, [1, 2]], [1, 2]));
console.log(include([1, 2, 3, [1, 2]], [1, 2, 3]));
console.log(include([1, 2, { a: 1 }, 4], { a: 1 }));
console.log(include([1, 2, { a: 1, b: 2 }, 4], { a: 1 }));
console.log(include([1, 2, 'abc', 4], 'abc'));
```

Comment: While it is true that stringifying each property incurs some level of processing, it is also true that the algorithm for stringifying is very similar to the approach that would be used to recursively check these values anyway. This answer could perhaps also use a small explanation of why comparing two different arrays with the same values to each other results in false.

Comment: Might also make sense to cache the `value` string instead of computing it in each iteration as well. Just in case anyone in the future comes along and uses this as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here we can do this using `Array.prototype.some()`

Notice we added a helper method to check each element, I did not bother writing object checking, but you get the idea.

Tweaked to support sub-arrays

```js
let arr = [1, [9, 9], 3, 4, 5];
let el = [9, 9];

let arr2 = [1, [1,[9, 9]], 3, 4, 5];
let el2 = [1,[9, 9]];

const someCheck = (item, compare) => {
  if(typeof item !== typeof compare) return false;
  if(typeof item === 'string') return item === compare;
  if(typeof item === 'number') return item === compare;
  if(Array.isArray(item)) {
    console.log('checking array');
    return item.reduce((accum, o, i) => accum && (someCheck(o,compare[i])));
  }
  // no plain object support yet.
  return false;
}


if (arr.some(e => someCheck(e, el))) {
  console.log(`the array contains ${el}`);
} else {
  console.log(`doesn't contain ${el}`);
}

if (arr2.some(e => someCheck(e, el2))) {
  console.log(`the array contains ${el2}`);
} else {
  console.log(`doesn't contain ${el2}`);
}
```

Comment: And `[9, [9, 9]]`? ;D

Comment: The `o === compare[i]` would need to be recursive into someCheck for that.

Comment: Now supports sub arrays.